# Table content disappears when buttons clicked in Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I have a problem with my edit and delete functions. Whenever I click the buttons in the table, the data disappears. Here's the full code:

```
            <h1>Player Rankings</h1>
            <v-table fixed-header height="500px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center" v-for="header in headers" :key="header.title">
                            {{ header.title }}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="">
                    <tr v-for="player in players" :key="player.playerName">
                        <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ player.score }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <v-btn color="primary" dark @click="showEdit(player)">
                                Edit
                            </v-btn>
                            <v-dialog v-model="editDialog" persistent max-width="700">
                                <v-card color="cyan" variant="outlined">
                                    <v-card variant="outlined" class="pa-4 ma-2 bg-black" color="yellow">
                                        <v-card-title class="text-h5 text-center text-white">
                                            Edit Player Information
                                        </v-card-title>
                                        <v-card-text>
                                            <form ref="formX">
                                                <v-text-field label="Player Name" solo dense class="text-white"
                                                    v-model="players.name" variant="filled">
                                                </v-text-field>
                                                <v-text-field label="Player Score" solo dense class="text-white"
                                                    v-model="players.score" variant="filled">
                                                </v-text-field>
                                            </form>
                                        </v-card-text>
                                        <v-card-actions>
                                            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                            <v-btn color="white" text @click="editDialog = false">
                                                Cancel
                                            </v-btn>
                                            <v-btn color="yellow" text @click="editPlayer">
                                                Save
                                            </v-btn>
                                        </v-card-actions>
                                    </v-card>
                                </v-card>
                            </v-dialog>

                            <v-btn color="error" class="ml-2" dark @click="showDelete(player)">
                                Delete
                            </v-btn>
                            <v-dialog v-model="deleteDialog" persistent max-width="700">

                                <v-card color="cyan" variant="outlined">
                                    <v-card variant="outlined" class="pa-4 ma-2 bg-black" color="yellow">
                                        <v-card-title class="text-h5 text-center text-white">
                                            Delete Player Information
                                        </v-card-title>
                                        <v-card-text>
                                            <p>Are you sure you want to delete {{ players.name }}?</p>
                                        </v-card-text>
                                        <v-card-actions>
                                            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                            <v-btn color="white" text @click="deleteDialog = false">
                                                Cancel
                                            </v-btn>
                                            <v-btn color="yellow" text @click="deletePlayer">
                                                Delete
                                            </v-btn>
                                        </v-card-actions>
                                    </v-card>
                                </v-card>
                            </v-dialog>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </v-table>
        </v-col>
    </div>
</div>



 </template>
  <script>
       import {collection,onSnapshot,doc,updateDoc,deleteDoc} from "firebase/firestore";
       import db from '@/firebase';
       export default {
        data: () => ({

        currentPlayer: {
            name: '',
            score: '',
        },

        defaultPlayer: {
            name: '',
            score: '',
        },

        players: {
            name: '',
            score: '',
        },

        headers: [{
                title: 'Name',
            },
            {
                title: 'Score',
            },
            {
                title: 'Actions',
            },

        ],

        editDialog: false,
        deleteDialog: false,
        docRef: null,
    }),
    watch: {
        editDialog(val) {
            val || this.closeEdit()
        },
        deleteDialog(val) {
            val || this.closeDelete()
        },
    },
    created() {
        // to fetch data
        this.initialize();
    },
    methods: {
        async initialize() {
            onSnapshot(collection(db, "players"), (snapshot) => {
                let playerz = []
                snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    playerz.push({
                        ...doc.data(),
                        id: doc.id
                    })
                });
                this.players = playerz;
            })
        },

        async showEdit(player) {
            this.players = Object.assign({}, player);
            const playerID = this.players.id;
            this.docRef = doc(collection(db, "players"), playerID);
            this.editDialog = true;
        },

        async editPlayer() {
            await updateDoc(this.docRef, {
                name: this.players.name,
                score: this.players.score,
            })
            this.closeEdit();
            console.log("Updated Successfully")
        },

        showDelete(player) {
            this.players = Object.assign({}, player);
            const playerID = this.players.id;
            this.docRef = doc(collection(db, "players"), playerID);
            this.deleteDialog = true;
        },

        async deletePlayer() {
            await deleteDoc(this.docRef);
            this.closeDelete();
            console.log("Deleted Successfully!")
        },

        closeEdit() {
           // this.resetForm();
            this.editDialog = false
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.currentPlayer = Object.assign({}, this.defaultPlayer)
            })
        },

        closeDelete() {
            //this.resetForm();
            this.deleteDialog = false
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.currentPlayer = Object.assign({}, this.defaultPlayer)
            })
        },

        resetForm() {
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.$refs.formX.reset();
            })
            
        },


    }
}
```

How do I fix it? I tried using the currentPlayers as its placeholder but I can't get the ID. I can't use the edit and delete function if i did it. Meanwhile in players, I can update and delete the information but whenever I cancel the functions, the data in the table is lost. Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is because you are assigning selected `player` to `players` array.

In both edit and delete methods you have `this.players = Object.assign({}, player)`

I think you mean to have `this.currentPlayer = Object.assign({}, player)` instead